# MySQL returns data where I just want to set value

Tags: mysql

I am new to mySQL my background is SQL Server

I have this SP that has this statement

```
DELIMITER //

create PROCEDURE spTest ()

BEGIN

declare vCnt int;
declare vMax int;

select vCnt = count(*), vMax=Max(ShortID) from ShrtMain;

select vCnt * vMax as Total;

END
```

I am expecting to one result with one field called Total

but what I actually get 2 results
one with 2 columns as shown here
[image]

and the other is what I actually want

[image]
how can I get just one result ?

Comment: I'm not following this question, you are running a SELECT query therefore results will be returned, no? Can you please clarify what you mean. If you are trying to insert a new record, use `INSERT` if you want to update an existing record use `UPDATE` if you want to pull records use `SELECT`.

Comment: You should provide the complete SP code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set a variable from a `SELECT` inside a MySQL stored procedure you use the [`SELECT ... INTO`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html) form of the query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO LimitCount 
FROM Locations 
WHERE IPAddress = IPAddress;
```

Note that it's inadvisable to use variables with the same name as columns (e.g. `IPAddress` in your query) as there is the potential for MySQL not to be able to determine which you want to use.